# Sequential Continuity vs. $\varepsilon-\delta$ Continuity

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

**When is it recommendable to use sequential continuity and when $\varepsilon-\delta$ continuity?**

It's probably difficult to answer this in all generality but surely there are times where it's clear that one is handier. What would be the intuition in those cases?

E.g. perhaps there are problems/statements/... that are simply more of a sequential nature. So one continuity just seems to "fit" better etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you are talking about Heine Theorem for functions of the form $f:A\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, where $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$.

We need to bear in mind that the sequential continuity and the $\varepsilon-\delta$ continuity are NOT equivalent in ZF.

More precisely, Heine Theorem holds under ZF + the Axiom of Choice.
However, in ZF, we only have $\varepsilon-\delta$ continuity $\Rightarrow$ sequential continuity and the converse is false in general.

Comment: Actually, I'm only talking about the elementary continuity definitions: $\varepsilon-\delta$ and a function is continuous at $x_0$, if for all sequences $x_n \to x_0$ we also have $f(x_n) \to f(x_0)$. For the function, I'd just take $f: A \to \mathbb{R}$ or $f: A \to \mathbb{C}$ with $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ or $A \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ but I guess metric spaces would be fine as well.

Comment: Exactly. The "equivalence" of the two definitions is known as Heine Theorem. However, the proof of sequential continuity $\Rightarrow$ $\varepsilon-\delta$ continuity requires the Axiom of Choice. It has been demonstrated that without the Axiom of Choice, this direction does not hold in general.

Comment: Assuming the Axiom of Choice, we are free to switch from one definition to the other. Regarding your question, in general, sequential continuity is easier to use, especially, when you deal with measure theory. It is because a lot of results will break if one works beyond countable cardinality.

Comment: Oh wow I see. Sorry, I did not know that - now that you have said that, I can see that in my proof I used the Axiom of Choice. I guess that also the reason why one direction is more difficult than the other. Very interesting, thanks!

Comment: To be slightly more exact, it requires the axiom of countable choice, which is weaker than the full axiom of choice.